# Turbolinks 5 Android Adapter Deep Link

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am working with a Ruby on Rails application with Turbolinks 5 enabled. I am trying to enable deep links so we can send a user a link and have it open within the application. I have everything setup in the AndroidManifest and a link is opening the app, but it doesn't navigate to the path.

I have tried just adding the intent filter to the Main activity, with no success and I have tried directing the intent to a seperate activity with calls the activity with Turbolinks.

We are using a custom scheme, because the user will point to the server they want to use via android preferences, it is not the same for every user.

```
public class DeepLinkNavigatorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String location;
    private static final String INTENT_URL = "intentUrl";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent thisIntent = getIntent();
        Uri uri = thisIntent.getData();
        location = uri.getPath();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TurbolinksActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(INTENT_URL, location);
        this.startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

I am still not able to get the application to browse to path.